# A function does not return the counter

Tags: javascript

I want to create a countdown.

```js
const useCountDown = (time = 3) => {
  let timeleft = time;
  const downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
    timeleft -= 1;
    if (timeleft <= 0) clearInterval(downloadTimer);
  }, 1000);
  return timeleft;
};
console.log(useCountDown(10))
```

I expect to return the coutdown from 10 to 0, but i get just 10. 
 How to get updated value in return and why i don't get the countdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that `setInterval` is an asynchronous function, so using synchronous javascript will not work.

This is a nifty solution using [Generator Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and callbacks.

```js
function* number(time) {
  for (let timeleft = time; timeleft !==  0; timeleft--) {
    yield timeleft;
  }
}
function countdown(callback, time = 3) {
  let num = number(time);
  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    var next = num.next();
    if (next.done) clearInterval(interval);
    callback(next.value || 0);
  }, 1000);
}

countdown((val) => console.log(val), 10);
```

Comment: BTW the generator function is sorta useless, its really just for show haha

Answer (score 1):

your `return timeleft` is a very strange idea.
if you want to show the countdown evolution, place the console.log inside the setInterval:

```js
const useCountDown = (time = 3) =>
  {
  console.log( time )
  let   timeleft      = time
  const downloadTimer = setInterval(()=>
    {
    console.clear()
    console.log( --timeleft )
    if (timeleft <= 0) clearInterval(downloadTimer)
    }
    , 1000) 
  }
  
useCountDown(10)
```

If you need to make a repetitively call of particular function you can use it by argument :

```js
const useCountDown = (time = 3, callfunction ) =>
  {
  callfunction( time )
  let   timeleft      = time
  const downloadTimer = setInterval(()=>
    {
    callfunction( --timeleft )
    if (timeleft <= 0) clearInterval(downloadTimer)
    }
    , 1000) 
  }

useCountDown(10, console.log )
```

Comment: i want to use the function in my code like:  `const countdownValue = useCountDown(10)`, and in console.log(countdownValue )  to get the countdown value. It is possible to do this?

Comment: i need this function in many places in my code this is why i need to return a value in the above function. Could you help?

Comment: @Asking a function called can only return a unique value (or record) and it'is happen only once, you can't have many execution plus return from a function

Comment: @Asking if you're okay with callbacks, I edited my answer

Comment: @Asking  : as I found your question really intriguing, I added a second answer in...

Answer (score 0):

When you call useCountDown(10), it will start fresh execution of code and create separate memory for all variables

so instead of return **timeleft** variable, return function and execute that function later

Ex:

```js
var useCountDown = (time = 3) => {
  let timeleft = time;
  const downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
    timeleft -= 1;
    if (timeleft <= 0) clearInterval(downloadTimer);
  }, 1000);
    
  return ()=> timeleft;
};

var counter = useCountDown(10);

let timeout = setInterval( ()=>{
    let count = counter();
    console.log(count)
    if(count < 1){
       clearInterval(timeout)
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, what you're trying to do isn't really allowed in JavaScript. A function can't return more than one value over time.

It can return an array, but that doesn't look like it would work for you.

It can return an object with a timeout *value* that updates over time:

```
function countdown(seconds) {
  const timer = { secondsInitial: seconds, secondsRemaining: seconds }
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    timer.secondsRemaining = timer.secondsRemaining - 1
    if (timer.secondsRemaining === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, 1000)

  return timer
}
```

Now whenever you access `timer.secondsRemaining` elsewhere in your code, it will contain the number of seconds left on your countdown timer.

However, there is a limitation here. I am guessing that it's quite likely you want things to happen when the timer updates. This setup lets you see what the timer is, but it doesn't automatically let you do something when that value changes. For that, in one way or another, you would need to provide a 'callback' containing the code you want to execute each second of the countdown.

Here's a simple way to handle that aspect of it. First we modify the countdown function to accept a callback:

```
function countdown(seconds, callbackFunction = undefined) {
  const timer = { secondsInitial: seconds, secondsRemaining: seconds }

  // Execute once at the top of the countdown
  if (callbackFunction) {
    callbackFunction(timer.secondsRemaining, timer.secondsInitial)
  }

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    timer.secondsRemaining = timer.secondsRemaining - 1
    if (callbackFunction) {
      callbackFunction(timer.secondsRemaining, timer.secondsInitial)
    }
    if (timer.secondsRemaining === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, 1000)

  return timer
}
```

Let's say what we want is just to log the timer. Then we would call the above function like this:

```
countdown(
  10,
  (remaining) => {
    if (remaining === 0) {
      console.log("NOW!!!")
    } else {
      console.log(`${remaining}...`)
    }
  }
)

/** Output
10...
9...
8...
7...
6...
5...
4...
3...
2...
1...
NOW!
*/
```